# Xfce IBus layout switching not working

Tags: xubuntu, keyboard-layout, xfce, ibus

Somehow, only default Xfce keyboard layout switching is working for me. When I remove all hotkeys from Xfce settings manager and try to switch to IBus I can change layouts from IBus widget, but hotkeys are not working for me.

How this can be resolved?

Answer (score 1):

The default works well for me <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>.

1. Run `ibus-setup`
2. *Advanced* tab → Uncheck *Use system keyboard layout*
3. If it didn't work, *General* tab → Change *Net input method* shortcut to something else.

Answer (score 0):

The default works not well for me Super+space.

Run ibus-setup
Advanced tab → Uncheck Use system keyboard layout
and change key super to alt(alt+space), it worked for me.